# Change internal custom field ids in JIRA

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I am implementing a job importing entries into JIRA via REST API. Each JIRA entry has a bunch of custom fields which have to be filled. Unlike the JIRA default fields custom fields are created with a meaningless internal id (customfield-'incremental-number').

It would be really painful to find out which custom field number belongs to which field. Furthermore currently I am running on a test system and the ids will probably change with the switch to production system...

Is there any possibility to rename the internal JIRA field id of custom fields?

Comment: Have you considered addressing the custom fields by name instead?

Comment: @ScottDudley
Addressing the custom fields by name doesn't work.

`Response:
{"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"xxx":"Field 'xxx' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown."...`

I have tryed this already.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the id of custom fields but you can use the REST API to find the list of names and ids: /rest/api/latest/field

Comment: Okay this helps at least to create the mapping table. Thanks for the hint.